# Problem: Formatting Table Column using Evaluate returning #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean up a table column. The values in the column may be zero, multiple dates separated by comma (text format), or a single date (date format).

Each cell in the column needs to include the most recent date only.

I am trying to do this with the Evaluate function but it is returning #VALUE for all cells.

```
Sub FixDateColumn()
    Dim PatientTable As ListObject

    Set PatientTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    PatientTable.ListColumns.Add.Range = _
    Evaluate("IF(LEN([@[Order Date]])>5,TEXT(DATEVALUE(RIGHT([@[Order Date]],10)),""m/d/yyyy""),TEXT([@[Order Date]],""m/d/yyyy""))")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using `[]` instead of `Evaluate`. See this

```
PatientTable.ListColumns.Add.Range = _
["=IF(LEN([@[Order Date]])>5,TEXT(DATEVALUE(RIGHT([@[Order Date]],10)),""m/d/yyyy""),TEXT([@[Order Date]],""m/d/yyyy""))"]
```

`Evaluate` and `[]` are not the same.

`Evaluate` will give an error if it is not able to evaluate the expression. `[]` is more like entering the formula directly in the worksheet.

Here is an example

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("LEN(""BLAH"")") '<~~ Returns 4
Debug.Print ["=LEN(""BLAH"")"]        '<~~ Returns =LEN("BLAH")
```

Now try

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("LEN([@[Order Date]]") '<~~ Returns Error 2015
Debug.Print ["=LEN([@[Order Date]]"]        '<~~ Returns =LEN([@[Order Date]]
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the difference between square brackets and Evaluate? I'm not quite sure I understand how they're different.

Comment: I did explain it with an example in the post above?